# Help identifying a 4 pin and 3 pin screw on connector?

Tags: connector, identification

I'm hoping to identify the name of the connectors pictured here.

The inner diameter of the threaded ring is roughly 13mm, the outer diameter is roughly 18mm. The pin spacing is roughly 3.5mm. The slot  in the threaded ring is a little under 2mm.

[image: 3 pin Plug]
[image: 4 pin Plug]
[image: Valley Lab Cautery machine back]

Comment: Mini xlr for the first one?

Comment: Looks like Amphenol mil circular connectors. <https://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/partgroup/mil-5015-97/2203?mpart=97-3102A-14S-2S&vendor=339>    These are standardized, multiple manufacturers.

Comment: I think the Amphenol mil connectors are the correct ones! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It could be something like our PM Series: https://www.milnec.com/mil-spec-connectors/mil-5015/.

Do the connectors have any identifying marks on them?